# Remove confirmation page in Drupal Installation Profile

Tags: installation

I'm doing some maintenance on a an installation profile I wrote for my small team. One of the annoyances that I am trying to remove is the confirmation page after the install is finished ("Congratulations! You have successfully installed Drupal"). Is there any to skip this page if the install is successful?

So far, the core [`install_finished`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!install.core.inc/function/install_finished/7) function, seems to be the only thing I can find that actually handles this step. But I'd rather not kill kittens over this : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never tried it but the docs for [`hook_install_tasks_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install_tasks_alter/7) suggest it's possible since `install_finished()` it one of those tasks

> Alter the full list of installation tasks.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> $tasks: An array of all available installation tasks, including those provided by Drupal core. You can modify this array to change or replace any part of the Drupal installation process that occurs after the installation profile is selected.

So in theory you should be able to replace the function for that entry with one that performs a redirect instead

```
function MYPROFILE_install_tasks_alter(&$tasks, $install_state) {
  $tasks['install_finished']['function'] = 'MYPROFILE_install_finished';
}

function MYPROFILE_install_finished(&$install_state) {
  // install_finished() still needs to run but we can discard the output.
  install_finished($install_state);
  drupal_goto('<front>');
}
```

Comment: I've done this type of install profile stuff (look through my answers here). The only tough part is that these functions have to go into their own `install profile` which has other pre-requisites beyond what you've described here. But this is the core change thats important! :)

Comment: I've included this in the ``.install`` of my installation profile and it is working wonderfully. Thanks!